# How to map a generic class to a generic array of the same class in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I am wondering, how you can map a generic class to a generic array of the same type in Kotlin.

Given following class:

```kotlin
class <T> MyClass(val type : Class<T>) {
  fun new() = type.newInstance()
}
```

I would like to have something like:

```kotlin
class MyOtherClass {
  val map = Map<Class<T>, MyClass<T>>

  inline fun <reified T> get() : MyClass<T> {
    if(T::class.java in map) {
      return map[T::class.java]
    } else {
      val newInstance = MyClass(T::class.java)
      map[T::class.java] = newInstance
      return newInstance
    }
  }
}
```

However, this does not work because:

- T cannot be used in MyOtherClass
- changing T to Any in MyOtherClass will throw a type inference error that Any is needed but we have T
- changing to out Any does also not work
- changing  to  does work but gives a warning that 'return map[T::class.java]' is an unchecked cast

I don't know how and if you can write that but from a logical point of view I want to achieve the following:

- have a generic manager class that does certain things for a given type (=MyClass above)
- have another class that caches such manager classes by their type. If a manager of the given type exists, then it should use that one instead of creating a new one
- Therefore, I would like to map a type to a manager of the same type

As mentioned, I have one way to write it which would be the following but I would like to avoid the casting warning because in my opinion it is not valid since the map should tell the compilter that getting something of type X will return a MyClass of type X.

```kotlin
class MyOtherClass {
  val map = Map<Class<out Any>, MyClass<out Any>>

  inline fun <reified T:Any> get() : MyClass<T> {
    if(T::class.java in map) {
      return map[T::class.java] as MyClass<T>
    } else {
      val newInstance = MyClass(T::class.java)
      map[T::class.java] = newInstance
      return newInstance
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: changing your map to `val map = mutableMapOf<Class<*>, MyClass<*>>()` and then in your method `return map[T::class.java] as MyClass<T>` works for me

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Don't you get a warning of an unchecked cast? At least that is what I am getting but maybe I do something different than you


And what exactly is "*"? I only know Any and Nothing in Kotlin.

Comment: `*` is a wildcard, thus you don't know what you're exactly working with. And the unchecked cast is a consequence, which you can't get around as far as I know

Comment: Yeah the warning is legitimate, as there's no longer compile-time type safety around it. You have to ensure that you're only storing sensible mappings, and then you can suppress the warning. You're basically telling the tools "I know what I'm doing here, this is safe."

Comment: thank you guys! I will write a clean answer tomorrow and close it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Lino and in the opening post, it is not possible without a warning because the generic information T is lost for Something.

Also, * can be used as a wildcard in Kotlin and therefore following approach is working (taken from the real code):

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> componentManager(): ComponentManager<T> = componentManager(T::class.java)

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T> componentManager(type: Class<T>): ComponentManager<T> {
        return when {
            componentManagers.containsKey(type) -> {
                componentManagers[type] as ComponentManager<T>
            }
            else -> {
                val manager = ComponentManager(initialEntityCapacity, type)
                addListener(manager)
                componentManagers.put(type, manager)
                manager
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to Lino!